# Async Task wont return to my task run call class

Tags: c#, multithreading, class, asynchronous, task

I have the following classes:

```
public struct _2CaptchaResult
{
    public bool Success;
    public string Response;

    public _2CaptchaResult(bool success, string response)
    {
        Success = success;
        Response = response;
    }
}

private async Task<_2CaptchaResult> SolveCaptchaAsync(string imagename)
{
    var result = await captcha.Solve...
    return new _2CaptchaResult
    {
        Success = result.Success,
        Response = result.Response,
    };
}

public async void login(string method)
{
    var result = await Task.Run(() => SolveCaptchaAsync(imagename));
    dostuff with the result...
}
```

When I run my `Task` everything works fine in the `SolveCaptcha` class. It feels like after the `SolveCaptcha` `Task` is done, it wont go back to the login class with the result, it just ends...

It still couldn't find out why it stops after the Task is finished. (`await Task.Run(() => SolveCaptcha(imagename));`)

I need to wait for the Captcha Solve Results before I can continue on my login class. The `SolveCaptcha` class works fine, I get my results from my `captcha.solve` call. But it wont pass the results to my login class, feels like it just stops after.

Thanks for any help, I'm a beginner in C#.

Comment: Chances are you are experiencing dead-lock. For the fun of it, try doing this: `var result = await Task.Run(() => SolveCaptcha(imagename)).ConfigureAwait(false);` instead of what you are currently doing in your `login` method

Comment: I was thinking of a dead-lock before, but I wasnt sure. Adding .ConfigureAwait(false); and it works now! Can you explain it? Much thanks.

Comment: eh, i didn't see that `SolveCaptcha` was already asynchronous. You don't need the `Task.Run()` wrapper. See the answer below. Just a tip: If a method is asynchronous, add the `Async` suffix. So it would be named `SolveCaptchaAsync()` Makes it easier to read and digest.

Comment: Answer was deleted. Try this: `await SolveCaptcha(imagename);`

Comment: Thanks I added the suffix. await SolveCaptchaAsync(imagename); still leads into a deadlock

Comment: OK -- then i will re-add my answer. Sorry for the confusion in this comment section. It's early and the ol' coffee hasn't kicked in yet :)

Comment: @Andy I deleted my answer cause it doesn't solve the problem. But yes, the Task.Run() is not necessary - I would guess the `async void` of the login method is the problem, cause the caller can't be awaiting it

Comment: The `login` method is `async void`, which [should be avoided](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/msdn-magazine/2013/march/async-await-best-practices-in-asynchronous-programming#avoid-async-void) for anything except event handlers. I suggest to change the return type to `Task`, and `await` the method properly.

Comment: @TheodorZoulias thanks I changed it! It works now properly.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Chances are you are experiencing dead-lock. For the fun of it, try doing this

```
var result = await Task.Run(() => SolveCaptcha(imagename)).ConfigureAwait(false);
```

instead of what you are currently doing in your `login` method.

The other thing I noticed, is `SolveCaptcha()` is already asynchronus, so you don't need the `Task.Run()` wrapper. Typically you use `Task.Run()` wrapper for CPU-bound work (think heavy processing like hashing, encryption, etc.) not I/O work (like reading from a socket or file.)

So in the end, it should look like this:

```
await SolveCaptcha(imagename).ConfigureAwait(false);
```

One more issue the should be corrected is your method that contains this line. You have it as `async void`, but it should be `async Task`. The caller will need a `Task` to await on and examine.

As far as how this dead-lock happens... there is plenty of information on it. Just google `c# async/await configureawait deadlock`. Here is [some more information](https://medium.com/bynder-tech/c-why-you-should-use-configureawait-false-in-your-library-code-d7837dce3d7f) to get you started (somewhere in the middle of the page, search for the word "deadlock" in bold)

Comment: I'd also consider removing `Task.Run`, if the method is already async, it doesn't really help much

Comment: Thanks, It looks like "await SolveCaptchaAsync(imagename).ConfigureAwait(false);" still leads into a deadlock. And with Task.Run it wont. The SolveCaptchaAsync has to be async because im calling an api call and i have to wait for it to be finished (await). The login class has also be async because im calling it often from different threads.

Comment: @tragbarerem -- well that's not good. We would need to see more of your code to determine if anything else could be causing the deadlock.

Comment: Yes i marked your answer as accept, maybe it has something to do how I call the login class. I´ll try to figure it more out.